# How to exclude specific logs from docker in fluentd when using match tag?

Tags: docker, grep, fluentd

I use docker to send logs to `fluentd`. The load of logs from modules is so huge that disk space gets full within 3 to 4 days. The `fluentd` config looks like:

```
<source>
  @type  forward
  @id    input1
  @label @mainstream
  port  24224
</source>

<filter **>
  @type stdout
</filter>

<label @mainstream>
 <match project_docker**mangox:latest**>
    @type elasticsearch
    host 172.16.131.102
    port 9200
    index_name project_mangox
    type_name mangox
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix project_mangox
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    buffer_queue_full_action drop_oldest_chunk
  </match>
</label>
```

I have gone through some documentation in `fluentd` to see if there is any and see that I can use [filter_grep](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/filter_grep), the problem is that I use `match` instead of `filter` tag.

**The question is**  how can I use something similar to grep in `match`? Or can I even use `filter_grep` in match tag? How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have record transformer plugin inside your match to remove unnecessary logs before storing them. You can refer the link [here](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/filter_record_transformer).

Comment: Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fluent-plugin-record-reformer/0.4.0 . Also, it looks something like this: <match foo.**>
  type record_reformer
  remove_keys remove_me
  renew_record false
  enable_ruby false

  tag reformed.${tag_prefix[-2]}
  <record>
    hostname ${hostname}
    input_tag ${tag}
    last_tag ${tag_parts[-1]}
    message ${message}, yay!
  </record>
</match>

Comment: [updated link](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/filter/record_transformer)